What does "overfitting" exactly means in linear regression?
I was trying to understand the overfitting concept. So I know that when the training R^2 is greater than 95% it means the model is overfitted and after doing some research I have the below understanding:
A model that captures noise and random fluctuations is learning to fit the data too closely, without considering the broader context or the underlying patterns. This can lead to poor performance on new, unseen data, as the model may be making predictions based on meaningless patterns that are not present in the real world.
And when a model "captures noise and random fluctuations" it means that it has learned to fit the random, meaningless patterns in the data rather than the underlying, meaningful relationships.
Upon research, I got to know that below could be the possible reasons why there is a chance of getting an overfitted model.

Outliers
Lots of low correlated Features w.r.t Target

Is my understanding correct? If not, please help me with some layman's answers and examples if possible.

A high in-sample $R^2$ might be suspicious when it’s way higher than expected (such as if similar problems get values like $0.2$), but strong in-sample performance does not, on its own, imply anything about overfitting.

Your understanding of overfitting is mostly correct! Overfitting happens when a model learns not just the true patterns in the data but also the noise or random fluctuations. This makes the model perform really well on the training data but poorly on unseen or test data because it's too focused on details that don’t generalize to new cases.
For example, think of overfitting like memorizing answers for a specific test, rather than understanding the underlying concepts. You’ll ace that test (high R² in training), but when given a different test, you might struggle (poor performance on new data).
As for causes, you're right—outliers and low-correlated features can lead to overfitting. Outliers are extreme values that the model tries too hard to fit, and lots of low-correlated features can add noise, making the model overly complex without improving predictions. Reducing the number of features, handling outliers, and using techniques like cross-validation or regularization can help prevent overfitting.
So overall, your understanding is solid, but focus more on simplifying the model and testing on unseen data to avoid overfitting.

Can I also say that if I get High R-squared on training data but low R-squared on validation/test data it means that the model is overfitted?

Yes, you can definitely say that! If your model shows a high R-squared on the training data but a low R-squared on validation or test data, it's a strong indicator of overfitting. This means that the model is fitting the training data very well, possibly even capturing noise or irrelevant details, but it struggles to generalize to new, unseen data. In simpler terms, the model has "memorized" the training data rather than learning the true patterns, so it performs poorly when faced with different data. This mismatch between training and test performance is a key sign your model is overfitting.

Cool thanks, Jeet. Also is it true that if my R^2 is greater than 95% then also it could mean that my model is overfitted?

@RushHour No, that’s not necessarily overfitting. It might be that a few variables explain most of what’s going on.
